# setf doesn't work as I think

Tags: common-lisp

I've just started leaning Common Lisp and I don't know why the code below returns 3:

```
(progn
  (setq lista '(1 2))
  (setq listb lista)
  (setf (nth 1 listb) 3)
  (nth 1 lista))
```

Can you help me, please?

Comment: What do you think SETF does?

Comment: I thought this macro is to change the value of a place designated to a new value.

Comment: It does and the modification is destructive. Which means you (try to) modify a literal list (1 2) to (1 3). Since lista and listb refer to the same list, there is no surprise here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Setq` does not copy things.  After `(setq listb lista)`, both names point to the same list.  When you modify it using one name, it also changes under the other.

If you want to create a copy, use `copy-list`, `copy-tree`, `copy-alist`, or `copy-seq` (see the [CLHS](http://clhs.lisp.se/)).  Also, don't modify literal data (things you `quote` (`'`) are literal data).

```
(let* ((list-a (list 1 2))
       (list-b (copy-list list-a)))
  (setf (nth 1 list-b) 3)
  (nth 1 list-a))
```

Comment: copy-tree solved the problem. Thank you for your help!